Infinitive usage after 'could do'

All she could do was to ask for help.

Question: Is the particle to needed after was or not?


All she could do was (to) ask for help.

The infinitive marker to is optional here as we have do in the subject noun phrase.
(I deleted the second part of my original answer.)

The second version doesn't sound right to me at all. Is it acceptable in BrE?

Thanks, @Barmar.  I always appreciate chances for me to clarify and also correct my answers.  The second version is indeed used.  I paste below a few links.  However, I have deleted that part of my answer as I found also usages without the infinitive marker.

All I could was to wait for Mama to come

All I could was to pray that the deal that was cut would work

all I could was to imagine her close to me

They all sound unnatural to me, I wonder if it's a dialect.
